# %extend tag and template methods

Tags: c++, templates, swig, extends

I have non-template class on C++ side is it possible to extend it with template method? So far it didn't work for me.

I've tried

```
%extend A {

  template <typename T>
  void fn(T t) {
    // some common code 
  }
}

%template (Afni) A::fn<int>;
...;
```

But `A::fn<int>` not generated for me in such way in cxx file.

So I have to use

```
%extend A {

  void fn(int t) {
    // some common code 
  }
  ...
}
```

drawback of such approach is duplication of the same common code.

Answer (score 0):

SWIG must know how to translate templated types. Every type not translated by default should be defined for SWIG with `%typemap`. Concerning `%extend`, it should work like the following:

```
//This is for compiling cxx as an ordinary cpp
%header %{
#include "class_header.h"
}

//OriginalClass is defined in the "class_header.h".
//So, it is already known to SWIG but not declared as the destination class.
//Here is the class definition for the destination code.
//All members defined in it supported by SWIG with the appropriate proxying code.
class OriginalClass {
    //Here you may declare all the members you want to access in the destination code
    inline const some_internal_type & get_data() const;
    //some_internal_type is assumed known to SWIG after declaring it with %typemap for in/out converting

    //Here is the whole block extending OriginalClass
    %extend {
        template<class T>
        void fn(T t) {
        }

        void setup(other_data p_dest) {
        //There is no the setup member in OriginalClass, but this method is available for the destination code
        //other_data is typemapped somewhere above for SWIG using %typemap
        }
    }
};
```

For each substituted `T` into `fn` SWIG should be provided with proper `%typemap` for representing that `T` in the proxying code.